# Pong game bugging out - mayby pointer to class

Tags: c++

get a problem with my code, this is just an extract from a larger piece of code involving OpenGL but still demonstrates the problem. It works without the collision detection call (col.detect()) - if you consider unbouncy walls working - but when I uncomment it the program breaks. Nothing seems to be wrong with the code itself it compiles just fine but doesn't work the way that I am expecting.

Thanks for all the help
Best Regards

**collision.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Ball.h"

class collision
{
public:
    collision();
    collision(Ball ball);
    void detect();
    ~collision();
private:
    Ball *point;
};
```

**Ball.h**

```
#pragma once
class Ball
{
public:
    Ball();
    double getpx();
    double getpy();
    double getvx();
    double getvy();

    void setpx(const double px);
    void setpy(const double py);
    void setvx(const double vx);
    void setvy(const double vy);

    void update();
    ~Ball();
private:
    double position[2] = { 0, 0 };
    double velocity[2] = { 0.1, 0 };
};
```

**collision.cpp**

```
#include "collision.h"

collision::collision()
{
}

collision::collision(Ball ball)
{
    point = &ball;
}

void collision::detect()
{
    if (point->getpx() > 1 || point->getpx() < -1)
        point->setvx(-point->getvx());
    else if (point->getpy() > 1 || point->getpy() < -1)
        point->setvy(-point->getvy());
}

collision::~collision()
{
}
```

**Ball.cpp**

```
#include "Ball.h"

Ball::Ball()
{
}

double Ball::getpx()
{
    return position[0];
}

double Ball::getpy()
{
    return position[1];
}

double Ball::getvx()
{
    return velocity[0];
}

double Ball::getvy()
{
    return velocity[1];
}

void Ball::setpx(const double px)
{
    position[0] = px;
}

void Ball::setpy(const double py)
{
    position[1] = py;
}

void Ball::setvx(const double vx)
{
    velocity[0] = vx;
}

void Ball::setvy(const double vy)
{
    velocity[1] = vy;
}

void Ball::update()
{
    position[0] += velocity[0];
    position[1] += velocity[1];
}

Ball::~Ball()
{
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Ball.h"
#include "collision.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    Ball tennis;
    collision col(tennis);

    while (true)
    {

        tennis.update();
        col.detect();

        cout << tennis.getpx() << endl;
        cin.get();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Edit: changing the if statement to else if in collision::detect() solved the part where the program doesn't run when I use col.detect(); but this stops me from testing both the x and y collision conditions at once.

Comment: Learn the differences between pointers, references and values and how to use a debugger. You likely need `collision::collision(Ball& ball)`, now you're makeing a copy of Ball, taking the address of that variable which gets destructed when the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

Below will cause your program to invoke Undefined Behavior when next you use `point`:

```
collision::collision(Ball ball)
{
    point = &ball;
}
```

Where `point` is defined to be:

```
Ball *point;
```

The problem is that you are storing the address of an object with *automatic storage-duration*. `ball` will cease to exist after that function completes hence leaving `point` to point ot an invalid object.

You probably wanted to take the ball by reference; or better still use the services of [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) in your program.

Comment: Oops silly mistake, thanks for the help... additional info on pointers really useful to know as well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code

```
collision::collision(Ball ball)
```

to

```
collision::collision(Ball& ball)
```

It should solve your problem. The problem was that Ball was a local variable whose address is no longer valid after the constructor exits. Solution : Send the object by reference and the address stored in the pointer will be of the object created in the main() function.